# Sum cells in multiple rows/columns with two different criterias in rows and columns

Tags: excel, sum, match, offset, sumifs

I can sum 2024 Q1 columns with criteria "Fernando" but only 9th row. (Below formula)

Please help.

Thank tou

[image: Sampl Image]

I tried below function but it sums only first matching row not all.

SUMIF($B$5:$S$5;C$1;OFFSET($B$5:$S$5;MATCH($B2;$A$6:$A$18;0);0))

I wish to sum "Fernando" in 9th,13th and 17th row (so on) all together in 2024 Q1 criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM((($B$6:$F$6=C1)*$B$7:$F$11)*($A$7:$A$11=B2))
```

Result:

[image]

Adapt to your ranges.

Comment: Thank you. It works very good. Please have  a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know which columns you want to sum it is not necessary to search for "2024 Q1"

Try this

```
= SUMIF(A:A,B2,N:P)
```

If you need sum of further quarters (e.g. 2024 Q2) you can place in D1:D2

|  | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024 Q1 | 2024 Q2 |  |
| 2 | = SUMIF(A:A,B2,N:P) | = SUMIF(A:A,B2,Q:S) |  |